# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect()

Tags: php, mysqli, apache

Instalé Apache, Mysql y PHP manualmente en Windows 11. Cuando intento ejecutar mysqli_connect () aparece el siguiente error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function
> mysqli_connect()

El código que estoy ejecutando se ejecuta normalmente en el servidor remoto:

```
class conectaClass
{

    /**
     * @access private
     */
    private $servidor = 'localhost';
    private $usuario = 'root';
    private $senha = 'P4ss$2021';
    private $banco = 'modelo';

    /**
     * @access protected
     */
    protected $conecta;

    /**
     * Classe faz a conexão ao banco de dados
     * @return $this->conecta
     */
    public function conectar()
    {
        $this->conecta = mysqli_connect($this->servidor,$this->usuario,$this->senha,$this->banco);
        mysqli_set_charset($this->conecta, "utf8");
        try
        {
            if (mysqli_connect_errno() != 0) 
            {
                $e = $this->erro(mysqli_connect_error());
                throw new Exception($e);
            }
             else
            {
                return $this->conecta;
            }
        }
         catch(Exception $e)
        {
        $this->conecta = 'Erro ao conectar. Se o erro persistir, entre em contato com suporte@isfast.com.br e informe o erro: CODPT_I: 0001';
        return $this->conecta;
        // return "<script>window.location.href='index.php';</script>";
        // exit();
        }
    } // Fim do método conectar()
```

Ya he desactivado la siguiente extensión en php.ini:

> extension=mysqli

Pero el problema persiste. Estoy usando Apache 2.4, PHP 7.4.25 y Mysql 8.0.

Lo que encuentro extraño es que cuando ejecuto phpinfo () en el servidor, aparece así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aunque desactivé la extensión extension = mysqli, cuando ejecuto phpinfo () localmente, esta información no aparece.

¿Como puedó resolver esté problema?

Comment: Intenta reiniciar apache primero.

Comment: Hola Marcelo. Ya reinicié, aun así el problema persiste :(

Comment: prueba habilitar
extension=php_mysqli.dll es decir, quita las ;  para dejarlo activo.

Comment: Aqui tienes un tutorial que seguramente te ayudara: http://www.codigogeek.com.mx/apache/como-instalar-apache-2-4-4-1-php-7-3-y-mysql-en-windows-10/  (yo de windows poco, lamento mi comentario anterior que ya he borrado)